# Supremum and infimum of a bounded real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I was reading a real analysis book online about supremum and infimum. When I came across this.

But it did not have any proof. I don’t see how it is «clear»
Would anyone mind proving it or explaining?[image]

Comment: Doesn't it follow immediately from the definition?

Comment: Do you know what is meant by supremum and infimum of  a set of real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

As f is defined on an non-empyset, $f(D)$ also is a nonempty set, therefore both $\inf f$ and $\sup f$ exist, and the inequalities hold. If they didn't, we'd have that there is an element $x_0 \in D$ such that $f(x_0)< \inf f$ or $f(x_0)>\sup f$, which contradicts the definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$

Comment: Yeah, but would the inf always be less or equal to the function itself?

Comment: I think you should review the definition of $\inf f $ and $\sup f$ very carefully

Answer (score 0):

You will always have, for $x \in D$ that
$\inf f = \inf_{y \in D} f(y) \le f(x) \le \sup_{y \in D} f(y) = \sup f$.

This is always true with the convention that $\inf_{y \in D} f(y) = -\infty$ if
$f$ is unbounded below on $D$ and similarly for $\sup$.